# How to upload multiple file at a time using TbActiveForm?

Tags: yii, upload

I am using TbActiveForm. I want upload multiple file at a time, Please help me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `TbActiveForm` you have to use a widget for multiple file upload. You could write it yourself or use widget like `CMultiFileUpload`.

Here is [reference for CMultiFileUpload](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMultiFileUpload).

Example for **view:**

```
<?php
  $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'attribute'=>'photos',
        'accept'=>'jpg|gif|png',
        'options'=>array(),
        'denied'=>'File is not allowed',
        'max'=>10, // max 10 files
  ));
?>
```

Example for **controller:**

```
public function actionCreate()

    {
        $model = new Photo;
        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
        $type = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : 'post';

        if (isset($_POST['Photo'])) {

            $model->attributes = $_POST['Photo'];

            $photos = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('photos');

            // proceed if the images have been set
            if (isset($photos) && count($photos) > 0) {

                // go through each uploaded image
                foreach ($photos as $image => $pic) {
                    echo $pic->name.'<br />';
                    if ($pic->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/photos/path/'.$pic->name)) {
                        // add it to the main model now
                        $img_add = new Photo();
                        $img_add->filename = $pic->name; //it might be $img_add->name for you, filename is just what I chose to call it in my model
                        $img_add->topic_id = $model->id; // this links your picture model to the main model (like your user, or profile model)

                        $img_add->save(); // DONE
                    }
                    else{
                        echo 'Cannot upload!'
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('update', 'id' => $model->id));
        }
        $this->render('create', array(
            'model' => $model,

        ));

    }
```

[Source reference.](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47613-uploading-file/page__p__223243#entry223243)